# Консольное приложение Yii2

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте.
Скажите пожалуйста как запустить консольное приложение на yii2, чтоб после закрытия вкладки терминала оно продолжило работать?

Answer (score 2):

Тут вопрос даже не в Yii2, а вообще в Linux, в нём это делается с помощью команды [nohup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

К примеру если ваша команда вызывается как `yii hello` вызовите её вот так:

```
nohup yii hello &
```

Укажите в конце символ `&`. Цитата из википедии:

> nohup не переводит автоматически команду в фоновый режим; пользователь
>   должен сделать это явным образом, завершив командную строку символом
>   «&».

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли!